# Convert year-week object to date and pass it to dateRangeInput() in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

Lets say I have a vector of year and week like: `yw<-c("2020-01","2020-02","2020-03")`. How can I pass it in `dateRangeInput()` as `start` and `end` date

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
yw<-c("2020-09", "2020-10", "2020-11") 

name<-c("AD","DF","FD")
value<-c(4,5,6)
df<-data.frame(yw,name,value)
v1 <- range(as.Date(paste0(df$yw, 1), format = '%Y-%W%w'),  na.rm = TRUE)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    
      dateRangeInput("dr", "Date range:",
                     start = v1[1],
                     end   = v1[2]),
  plotlyOutput("pl")
  )
  ,
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$pl<-renderPlotly({
      sub<-subset(df, yw==input$dr)
      
      plot_ly(sub,
              x = ~ yw, 
              y = ~value,
      ) %>%
        add_trace(
          type = 'scatter',
          mode = 'lines+markers',
          hoveron = 'points')
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the dates are in year-week format, concat with a dummy week day at the end using `paste`, convert to `Date` class and get the `range` of dates which can be used as `start` and `end` in `dateRangeInput`

```
v1 <- range(as.Date(paste0(yw, 1), format = '%Y-%W%w'),  na.rm = TRUE)
v1
#[1] "2020-01-27" "2021-04-05"
```

-shiny

```
..
fluidPage(
  dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Date range:",
                 start = v1[1],
                 end   = v1[2]),...
..
```

Comment: why if I do: as.Date(yw, format = '%Y-%W') I get "2020-05-06" "2020-05-06" "2020-05-06". That seems wrong. This is todays date while I passed 1st second and 3rd week of 2020

Comment: sorry, it should have a week day as well.  updated with paste

Comment: what does 1 mean?

Comment: @firmo23 it means weekday 1st.  Just a dummy one to make that work because we don't know which day from the week.  It can be monday, tues,, ,,. friday

Comment: when I ty to use your code to my actual vector which is just like yw but bigger I get In strptime(x, format, tz = "GMT") :
  (0-based) yday 369 in year 2020 is invalid and get NAs as a result

Comment: @firmo23 may be because the 1 doesn't exist.  Can you try 0 instead

Comment: I added my actual vector

Comment: what d u mean? I just added all my actual values. ur solution does not work on them for some reason

Comment: sorry I did that

Comment: @firmo23 these are the ones that cause this trouble `yw1[c(45, 109, 172, 235, 299)]`
[1] "2020-53" "2020-53" "2020-53" "2020-53" "2020-53"`, which may be that 53 doesn't exist for 2020 based on "%W" because it uses `Week of the year as decimal number (00–53) using Monday as the first day of week`.  You can specify the `range` with `na.rm = TRUE` and it will give the range